# "Slide to answer" alternative on Lollipop

Tags: calls, 5.1-lollipop, accessibility

I'm using ZTE Maven running Android 5.1 Lollipop, and while there are 3 physical buttons on the front of the phone beneath the display, by default to answer a call you have to touch a green virtual button on the display and "slide to answer".

I get calls very infrequently and when I do I have a lot of difficulty answering calls.  At first I concluded that I have to hold on the green virtual button until it activates, and then slide it, but recently that doesn't work either and I end up missing the call.

I understand there are apps for changing this behavior, but I'd prefer a configuration solution.  I think once I found a mention of an accessibility setting for this, but the only documentation I can now find is for pre-Lollipop versions of Android and it doesn't seem to apply.

Is there a way to configure Lollipop with an alternative way to answer calls?

Comment: If any of the already-existing answers has satisfactorily solved your problem, please accept the answer by adding a green checkmark.

Comment: You could use a Bluetooth headset's "answer call" button, but if you don't receive many calls, it might be a hassle to wear the headset all day.  Alternatively, maybe you could use a voice command to answer calls, but I have no idea whether or not this is really possible using the current version of the Google Assistant.

Comment: Do you have a visual impairment which makes it difficult to see where the call-answering slider is located? Or do you have issues with hand-eye coordination, which make it difficult to slide the slider? Or both?

Comment: @unforgettableid  I think it was more about that particular phone, as I have no trouble with slide-to-answer on iPhone 6s now

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Samsung Galaxy S-series, you can change the call answering and ending options in **Settings > Accessibility > More settings > Answering and Ending calls**. I didn't like the way it worked, I now have it set up so all I press is the home key.

The other one is **Single tap mode**, which is like its name, answering/rejecting incoming calls with a single tap.

[image: Samsung Galaxy S5 Accessibility]

<sup>Image courtesy of [AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-accessibility-options)</sup>

Comment: I don't see "More settings", are you using Android 5.1 Lollipop?

Comment: Yes, it isn't a selectable option,  more of a subcategory/title, it may be device specific, I'm unsure. What device are you using?

Comment: My device is a ZTE Maven, it only cost $50 but it is quite satisfactory in other respects

Comment: OK, from the image that I found on GSMarena, it looks like your phone doesn't have any hardware keys on the front, so i don't think that this will be an option. However, if you can see  single tap mode in your accessibility options, you could enable that, which would negate the need to slide the green/red icon to answer/reject calls. BEWARE: this does the same for  alarms, calendar events and timer alerts, so instead of sliding to dismiss, you would tap the icon

Comment: I do have three buttons on the front but they are behind the glass and I could see where they wouldn't be obvious in a photo.  While single tap mode sounds promising, I couldn't find that either.

Comment: Online documentation: http://www.att.com/devicehowto/?make=zte&model=ztez812 I'm getting the impression that I'm out of luck.

Comment: I'm away from pc at the moment  but as soon as I can, I'll explore it, there has to be a way, we just need to figure it out

Comment: I added the "Samsung device" since Samsung customized most of Android's stock feature.

Answer (score 1):

To find your "tap once", go to settings, accessibility, talkback, when you are in there, it has its own settings (top right hand corner), press that from there you scroll down the list until you see "single tap selection".  Don't know if it will work but it is worth a shot.

Comment: I have checked the box but TalkBack remains Off.  I'll let you know how it goes, thanks.

Comment: I've only taken 2 or 3 calls since then but I'd have to say it doesn't seem to have made a difference

Answer (score 1):

on an lg k20 go to settings> accessibility> motor and cognition> touch and hold for calls. hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Swipe once, then tap blue phone symbol once.